# How to solve cubic vector equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, numerical-methods, cubics

A cubic equation
$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$$
has three solutions, which can be found analytically.

Likewise, a vector equation like
$$\underline{\underline{A}} \underline{x} + c(\underline{x}^T\underline{x})\underline{x} + \underline{b} = 0$$
should have three vector solutions $\underline{x}_0,\underline{x}_1,\underline{x}_2$.
My question is, how do I find these? I would appreciate analytical ideas, but numerical solutions would also be fine, the only problem with the latter is that I need all three solution (or how many real solutions there are) rendering (at least in my mind) iterative methods infeasible.

If it helps we can assume $\underline{\underline{A}} = \text{diag} \underline{a}$.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't expect just three solutions. For example, in the case of a linear vector equation, the solution will correspond to a whole subspace in general.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expanding the vector equation and using the assumption for $A$, note that you get 3 cubic equations:

$$a_0 \, x_0+ c \, (x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)\, x_0 + b_0 = 0$$
$$a_1 \, x_1+ c \, (x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)\, x_1 + b_1 = 0$$
$$a_2 \, x_2+ c \, (x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)\, x_2 + b_2 = 0$$

you can solve this system of equations traditionally.

Comment: Thank you. I did realize this. But how do you solve $N$ simultaneous cubic equations? It is quite difficult (also numerically if you want all solutions). I was hoping that the above equation might have some better approach.

Comment: Also, a and b were vectors... So they are different in each equation.